# difference between apt and fit

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences

**Question**

I'm particularly interested in the meaning of apt, but while I was searching through some dictionaries and examples it struck me how close the words *apt* and *fit* seem to be. Thus: what exactly is the difference between apt and fit?

**Etymology**

As I understand from etymonline.com the word apt came from - next part copied from etymonline - from Latin *aptus* where it meant "fit, suited" which is related to *apere* "to attach, join, tie to". The Proto Indo European root is *ap-* and means to grasp, take, reach

Fit on the other hand seems to be somewhat more difficult to trace back. Etymonline states that mid 15th century it meant "suited to the circumstances, proper," though of unknown origin, perhaps from Middle English noun fit "an adversary of equal power" (mid-13c.) which in turn might be connected to Old English fitt "a conflict, a struggle"

**Additional Thoughts/Questions**

Reading the etymologies above, would it be fair to say that the difference between an apt student and a fit student would be that:

- an apt student is a student that has the right **conduct/behaviour** in regard to studying?
- a fit student is the student that is (especially physically) well **equiped** to engage in a struggle, e.g. study?

Anyway, the above is just an example to get the discussion started, but if you have broader views on the difference of apt and fit please share them as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say a fit student is a student who is in good physical shape (or, if you’re a British yoof, a good-looking one). I would not use ‘fit’ attributively in that way.

Comment: Yes, _fit_ is not much used without a _for_ or _to_ phrase, except in the specific senses that Janus suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Apt" and "fit" are generally not interchangeable, as one or the other tends to be preferred in a given context.  I think the degree of specificity is what distinguishes them.  "Fit" tends to means "well-suited *to a particular purpose*", while "apt" means "well-chosen" or "appropriate" in a more holistic sense.  Here are some examples:

- "This was an **apt** observation, given the events that followed."  The
  observation was especially well chosen in context, not for any
  particular purpose, so "fit" doesn't really work here.  However,
  "fitting" could be used.
- "The survey was designed to determine which candidate was most **fit**
  for the job." Since a specific purpose is cited, "fit" works better
  than "apt" here.
- "Joe proved an **apt** pupil, quickly surpassing his peers."  Here, "apt"
  is used to mean "skillful" in a general sense, without any particular
  purpose.
- "Only the most physically and mentally **fit** students can become underwater basket weavers."  Here the two words are pretty interchangeable, although perhaps "adept" would be better than "apt".

Answer (score 0):

*Fit* is a common enough term adjective used to note a degree of athleticism.  *Apt* is more commonly used when the skill under consideration is not particularly athletic.[image]

Comment: Still when looking at a phrase like survival of the fittest, this surely does not just refer to athleticism, does it? I would say it refers rather to species/individuals with the best tools (in relation to the environment) at disposal, in this case the body...

Comment: @Flabbergasted "Survival of the fittest" is a semi-technical term referring to "[evolutionary] fitness", the ability of an organism to live and reproduce in its environment.  The term is sometimes applied metaphorically to other situations, but this is its original meaning.